# How does Visual VM interact with JVM to get all the information ? Is there any API's exposed by JVM to do so?

Tags: jvm

How does Visual VM interact with JVM to get all the information. Is there any API's exposed by JVM to do so ? \

Answer (score 3):

Yes, this is done mostly through [JMX API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/jmx/index.html).

There are public standardized MBeans for JVM monitoring:

- [ThreadMXBean](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/management/ThreadMXBean.html)
- [RuntimeMXBean](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/management/RuntimeMXBean.html)
- [MemoryMXBean](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/management/MemoryMXBean.html)
- [ClassLoadingMXBean](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/management/ClassLoadingMXBean.html)
- etc., see [`java.lang.management`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/management/package-summary.html) package.

And there are also private HotSpot-specific MBeans under `sun.management` package:

- [HotspotClassLoadingMBean](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u/jdk/file/5afcccb74f00/src/share/classes/sun/management/HotspotClassLoadingMBean.java)
- [HotspotCompilationMBean](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u/jdk/file/5afcccb74f00/src/share/classes/sun/management/HotspotCompilationMBean.java)
- [HotspotMemoryMBean](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u/jdk/file/5afcccb74f00/src/share/classes/sun/management/HotspotMemoryMBean.java)
- [HotspotRuntimeMBean](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u/jdk/file/5afcccb74f00/src/share/classes/sun/management/HotspotRuntimeMBean.java)
- [HotspotThreadMBean](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u/jdk/file/5afcccb74f00/src/share/classes/sun/management/HotspotThreadMBean.java)

Besides JMX HotSpot JVM has other diagnostic APIs:

- [Jvmstat Performance Counters](http://openjdk.java.net/groups/serviceability/jvmstat/), aka PerfData
- [Dynamic Attach API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/jdk/api/attach/spec/)
- [JVM Tool Interface](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/platform/jvmti/jvmti.html)

By the way, VisualVM is open source, you may [download the sources](https://java.net/projects/visualvm/sources/svn/show/trunk) to see everything yourself.

Comment: Great summary! Thanks for showing the `Dynamic Attach API`, didn't know about that!